# Why comparing the length of sets to remove duplicates in a doubly linked list doesn't work? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, data-structures

so recently I was learning python data structure, more specifically, the "doubly linked list". I came across a problem where I need to write code to remove duplicates in a doubly-linked list and I tried to use set() since it doesn't allow duplicates. I compared the length of the sets before adding the new node from the linked list and after adding that node to see if there were any changes with the length, if no, deleting that node since the length didn't change implying that the node is a duplicate. Unexpectedly, this method just doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my remove_duplicate function:

```
def remove_duplicates(self):
    cur = self.head
    seen = set()
    while cur:
      temp = cur
      prev_len = len(seen)
      seen.add(cur)
      after_len = len(seen)
      if prev_len == after_len:
        self.delete_node(cur)
        cur = temp.next
      else:
        cur = cur.next
```

Here's the delete_node function:

```
def delete_node(self, node):
    cur = self.head
    while cur:
      if cur == node and cur == self.head:
        # Case 1:
        if not cur.next:
          cur = None 
          self.head = None
          return

        # Case 2:
        else:
          nxt = cur.next
          cur.next = None 
          nxt.prev = None
          cur = None
          self.head = nxt
          return 

      elif cur == node:
        # Case 3:
        if cur.next:
          nxt = cur.next 
          prev = cur.prev
          prev.next = nxt
          nxt.prev = prev
          cur.next = None 
          cur.prev = None
          cur = None
          return

        # Case 4:
        else:
          prev = cur.prev 
          prev.next = None 
          cur.prev = None 
          cur = None 
          return 
      cur = cur.next
```

And the node class and linked list class are:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
    self.prev = None


class DoublyLinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

  def append(self, data):
    if self.head is None:
      new_node = Node(data)
      self.head = new_node
    else:
      new_node = Node(data)
      cur = self.head
      while cur.next:
          cur = cur.next
      cur.next = new_node
      new_node.prev = cur

  def prepend(self, data):
    if self.head is None:
      new_node = Node(data)
      self.head = new_node
    else:
      new_node = Node(data)
      self.head.prev = new_node
      new_node.next = self.head
      self.head = new_node

  def print_list(self):
    cur = self.head
    while cur:
      print(cur.data)
      cur = cur.next
```

I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while, so any advice and corrections on my remove_duplicate function will be very appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate nodes? Nodes with the same data? If so, add node's data to the set, not the node itself...

Comment: yes, nodes with the same data

Comment: Oh, my bad, it should be cur.data inside the seen.add(). It still doesn't work tho

Comment: How does it still not work? Testing it myself shows that `remove_duplicates` works for simple examples once the `cur.data` value is what gets added to the set.

Comment: yea for some lists it did work, but for lists like 2->2->2->2 and 8->4->4->6->4->8->4->1....., it didn't work.

Comment: I guess it might be because of the order of my code inside if conditions or something

Comment: Learn how to debug. Construct a small example that fails. Either add `print()`s to show what's happening at each step or learn how to use the Python debugger. The goal is to close the gap between what you _think_ is happening and what actually does.  Figuring out problems like this on your own is a required element of the art of programming. Asking others to do it for you is not.  One other note is that doubly linked lists ought to be circular. Implementation is then much simpler.  For example, deletion is a single case, not all you've shown.

Comment: Why do you iterate in your `delete_node` method btw? It receives the node to delete already as the argument, and the node "knows" all you need to be able to delete it (left/right neighbor). I think deletion logic could be simplified drastically.

Comment: One other note is that inspecting the set size is a roundabout way of accomplishing what you want. The simpler logic is `if cur in seen: <do deletion> else seen.add(cur)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will definitely learn how to better debug for any future tasks, and honestly, I've hardly ever debugged any of my work in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. The first issue is that you're adding the `Node` instance, not the value within the node, to the `seen` set. Unless your linked list is circular, you're not going to run into the exact same node again, so you'll never see any duplicates this way.

Try adding the `data` attribute to the set instead of the node itself:

```
  prev_len = len(seen)
  seen.add(cur.data)      # add the data attribute, not the node itself to the set
  after_len = len(seen)
```

As was pointed out in the comments on your question, checking the length of the set is sort of a round-about way of membership testing. A simpler way would be to directly check `cur.data in seen`.

The other issue is more subtle, and has to do with how you delete your nodes and how you move to the next entry in the list, after finding and deleting your first duplicate.

Your code does:

```
    temp = cur
```

and then later:

```
    self.delete_node(cur)
    cur = temp.next
```

The problem is that `self.delete_node` modifies the node being deleted by setting its `prev` and `next` links to `None`. Since `temp` is just a reference to the node `cur` (not a copy), it sees the modified value, and so you can never delete more than one node from the list.

What would work better is saving the next node before the deletion, and then going directly to it:

```
temp = cur.next
self.delete_node(cur)
cur = temp
```

But really, you could avoid the issue by making `delete_node` not bother messing with the node being removed, since it's no longer linked to by any of the other nodes. The `delete_node` method could be radically simplified in a number of other ways into something like this:

```
def delete_node(self, node):   # no need to search for the node, we've already got it!
    if node.next:
        node.next.prev = node.prev

    if node.prev:
        node.prev.next = node.next
    else:
        self.head = node.next
```

With this deletion logic, you'd no longer need special case code for getting the next node in `remove_duplicates`, you would just unconditionally move on to `cur.next`.

```
def remove_duplicates(self):
    cur = self.head
    seen = set()

    while cur:
        if cur.data not in seen:
            seen.add(cur.data)
        else:
            self.delete_node(cur)

        cur = cur.next            # this now works even if we deleted cur
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the part where you said 'Since temp is just a reference to the node cur (not a copy)' what is the difference between 'reference' and 'copy' of the object?

Comment: In Python if you say `x = Node(0)` and then `y = x`, both `x` and `y` refer to the same object (that is, chunk of memory). So if you say `x.data = 42`, you are also changing the value of `y.data`.

Answer (score 0):

In case useful, since yours should be working by now, here is a more succinct doubly linked list implementation.

One thing to note is that Python's reference counting garbage collection won't free the circularly linked nodes even if the list itself is no longer referenced. The generational collector will get it eventually. If that's not good enough, you'll need to explicitly clear the next and prev references of the sentinel when the list is no longer needed.

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = self.prev = self

  def link_after(self, node):
    node.next = self.next
    node.prev = self
    self.next.prev = node
    self.next = node

  def unlink(self):
    self.prev.next = self.next
    self.next.prev = self.prev
    self.next = self.prev = None  # Enable gc


class DoublyLinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    # sentinel.next and .prev are list head and tail resp.
    self.sentinel = Node(None)

  def prepend(self, data):
    self.sentinel.link_after(Node(data))

  def append(self, data):
    self.sentinel.prev.link_after(Node(data))

  def nodes(self):
    node = self.sentinel.next
    while node != self.sentinel:
      next = node.next
      yield node
      node = next

  def data_values(self):
    for node in self.nodes():
      yield node.data

  def remove_duplicates(self):
    seen = set()
    for node in self.nodes():
      if node.data in seen:
        node.unlink()
      else:
        seen.add(node.data)

  def print_data(self):
    for data in self.data_values():
      print(str(data))


def test():
  list = DoublyLinkedList()
  for i in range(6):
    list.prepend(i)
  for i in range(6):
    list.append(i * 2)
  list.print_data()
  list.remove_duplicates()
  print
  list.print_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test()
```

Comment: Yeah, this implementation looks much more concise and clean.